# Music player that can speed up/slow down the music

Tags: media, playback

Is there a music player for Windows that will let me speed up / slow down my songs? I can do it for each song in Audacity, but that's too tedious, I don't want to resample my entire collection to new files, I just to listen to it in a bit more higher-pitched version.

Comment: As reference for others, meta question is [this one](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1987/my-question-was-closed-as-exact-duplicate-but-instead-was-exactly-the-opposite).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VLC Media Player.

Can adjust playback speed up or down, including fine adjustment.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Media Player can do this just fine. There's a panel which you can activate. It will not pitch the song higher, though! It will just go faster!

To activate: Go into the Windows Media Player menu (ALT), go to View and Extensions, playback speed.